# Images loaded from expansion file appears smaller than it should look

Tags: android, android-drawable, apk-expansion-files

I'm developing an app with many images. Some of the images I moved to expansion files, because of the app limit(50MB). Before I put all my images into different folders like drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc. Now I'm programmatically determining what dpi is the phone and getting images accordingly. Here are the important bits of code:

```
    public String getFolder()
    {
        String folder = "";
        int dpi = res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

        int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
        int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;

        float scaleFactor = metrics.density;
        float widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;
        float heightDp = heightPixels / scaleFactor;

        float smallestWidth = Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);

        if (smallestWidth > 720 && dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
            //Device is a 10" tablet
        } 
        else if (dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH||dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV) {
            //Device is a 7" tablet
            //xhdpi
            folder = "drawable-xhdpi/";
        }
        else if((smallestWidth > 480 && dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)|| dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
        {
            //hdpi
            folder = "drawable-hdpi/";

        }
        else if(dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH)
        {
            //xxhdpi
            folder = "drawable-xxhdpi/";

        }
        else if(dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
        {
            //mdpi
            folder = "drawable-mdpi/";

        }
        else if(dpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
        {
            //ldpi
            folder = "drawable-ldpi/";
        }

        return folder;
    }
public BitmapDrawable getDrawable(Context ctx, String imageName){
    String path = folder+imageName;
    ZipResourceFile zip;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
         zip = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(ctx, 9, -1);
        InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(path);
         b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bfo);     }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new BitmapDrawable(b);
}
```

So, whenever I need an image I call getDrawable like so:

```
newItem.setBackgroundDrawable(storage.getDrawable(this,"red_stored.png"));
```

But the problem is, now when I do it programmatically, the image appears smaller than if I would put it into drawable-xhdpi folder and android authomatically picks it from that folder. What can I do to solve this problem?